# Where is the Polyfuse of Raspberry Pi3?

Tags: pi-3b+

I wan to test the polyfuse of the Raspberry pi3 B+ I try to find where it is but it said in the search result locate the F3 but there is no F3 in the board written anyone can help?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_3bplus_1p0_reduced.pdf shows no polyfuse (or I can not find it)

Comment: F1 is the polyfuse in the schematic

Answer (score 1):

The polyfuse on the Pi3B+ is adjacent to the power socket, near the HDMI socket.

NOTE I strongly advise AGAINST poking test leads in a running Pi - if you must test do it on an unpowered Pi.

You would be better to just measure voltage on pin 2 of the expansion connecter.